# Excel look up values based on comma separated string values

Tags: excel

I need help with an Excel formula. I have to find the cell value based on a comma separated value list in another cell

For e.g Here G5 will have the max of Estimated End Date column (H) whose ID column contains values 1 or 2 (comma separated list in E5). Again above is e.g. there could be more than 2 values in the list

[image: Excel snippet]

so G5 here should be 09/03/22 since it is max of 04/03/22 and 09/03/22.

Comment: Left() and right() and vlookup().

Comment: @SolarMike the number of comma seperated value isn't fixed

Comment: Well, don’t waste our time if you can’t provide a clear and relevant example.

Comment: Wasn’t an answer, it was a comment. And a comment to give you a hint - to help yourself and improve.

Comment: If you have Excel 365 it should be fairly straightforward with textsplit and xlookup, otherwise more tricky with filterxml and index/match.

Comment: Maybe easier to check which ID row is in the comma string and filter accordingly, then max ?

Comment: Yes exactly, I was thinking the same thing but ran out of time to edit my comment! Have to be careful not to match 1 with 12 etc. of course

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Excel 365, the steps are:

1. Convert CSV to array
2. Map the array to found row numbers
3. Grab the max of the resultant array

I don't have the TEXT_SPLIT function, so I have to roll my own. I have a few helper functions for this (note these are saved as Names, in Formula->Define Name, so you'll need to add them).:

*csvText*

```
=LAMBDA(txt,"," & txt & ",")
```

*csvCount*

```
=LAMBDA(txt,LEN(txt)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(txt,",",""))-1)
```

*csvPosOf*

```
=LAMBDA(n,txt,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(txt,",","@",n)))
```

*csvLenOf*

```
=LAMBDA(n,txt,csvPosOf(n+1,txt)-csvPosOf(n,txt)-1)
```

*csvArray*

```
=LAMBDA(txt,MAKEARRAY(1,csvCount(txt),LAMBDA(r,c,TRIM(MID(txt,csvPosOf(c,txt)+1,csvLenOf(c,txt))))))
```

This covers the splitting of your csv text to an array.

The mapping of the IDs to row numbers and `MAX` call is simply this formula:

```
=MAX(MAP(csvArray(csvText(C3)),LAMBDA(v,INDEX($A:$H,MATCH(VALUE(v),$A:$A,0),8))))
```

You'd add this formula into each row of your G column. Again, adjust the cell references as you need them. Please note you must call the `VALUE` function on the LAMBDA expression, as you can't implicitly `MATCH` a text representation of a number to an actual number.